# Check whether an object is fully inside/overlapped by other objects in Unity3D?

Tags: unity, collision-detection, voxels

I have **structures made of voxels** (cube gameobjects), and I want to make **complex structures from them**.

But I **don't** always want to place them **on the grid**. I want them to be more realistic, like **diagonal**:

[image]

(Don't mind those visual artifacts)

(If I would want to make a fortress like this on the grid, these diagonals would be ugly and zigzaggy.)

My problem is that due to this there would be **double the voxels at the overlapping places**. I want to **remove every cube** (for example from the selected wall object) which are being **FULLY overlapped**.

This way there won't be double voxels (only partially at the edges, which is fine) and it would look good as well.

**How could I check this?** I don't want to modify the structures manually because both the angle and the other object may vary, thus one structure would need lots of variations.

Comment: Presumably you looked into methods like Physics.OverlapBox? How have you tried implementing this check so far?

Comment: How could I determine by that how overlapped the object is? Because I just want to know when an object is fully overlapped.